# R ggpairs rotate whole matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpairs

Okay so I'm trying to make a scatterplot matrix with ggpairs (see example below). But I want the whole matrix to be rotated counter-clockwise 90 degrees. And with this, I then want to rotate the axis text. Anytime I try to add any theme() onto ggpairs() and try to display the plot, I get NULL. Please help, this should be simple.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
library(MASS)
cars <- dplyr::select(Cars93, Type, Price, MPG.city, MPG.highway, 
              EngineSize, Origin)
ggpairs(cars)
```

Matrix as it is now

[image: matrix as it is now]

What I want the matrix to look like

[image: what I want matrix to look like]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the same as your image, but I think this is what you're looking for.

```
ggpairs(cars,
        upper = list(continuous = "points", combo = "facethist", 
                     discrete = "facetbar", "na"),
        lower = list(continuous = "cor", combo = "box_no_facet", 
                     discrete = "count", "na"),
        diag = list(na = "naDiag", discret = "barDiag", 
                    continuous = "densityDiag"))
```

The bottom and top row are swapped from what you asked for, but the orientation is what you were looking for (I think!).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `viewport` from `grid` in a `print` call to turn your object 90 like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
library(MASS)
library(grid)
cars <- dplyr::select(Cars93, Type, Price, MPG.city, MPG.highway, 
                      EngineSize, Origin)
p <- ggpairs(cars)
print(p, vp=viewport(angle=90, width = unit(4.5, "inches"), height = unit(4.5, "inches")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>